# what is the origin point in a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What determines the origin point when I draw a rectangle with TikZ?  In the example below the x coordinate of the origin seems arbitrary...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=3.25in,paperheight=2in,margin=.5pt ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1in, 1in);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really any difference between your example and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=3.25in,paperheight=2in,margin=.5pt ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
X
\end{document}
```

The `tikzpicture` is just seen as a big box, and is placed on the first line, indented with the standard paragraph indent, which `\noindent` removes. Add a letter right before or after the `tikzpicture`, and you'll see that the bottom of the `tikzpicture` is placed at the baseline, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=3.25in,paperheight=2.5in,margin=.5pt ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1in, 1in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
Z

 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1in, 1in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]